# How to rank svm_predict() output of libsvm in java?

Tags: java, ranking, libsvm

I am doing a classification task (-1 and +1) using LIBSVM in JAVA. In LIBSVM i use kernel_type=RBF and svm_type=C_SVC and all other parameter value are default.

**How do I rank output of svm_predict() in java?**

svm_predict() generates this file:

```
 labels 1 -1
-1.0 0.019641780896603997 0.9803582191033958 
-1.0 0.021318683904391962 0.9786813160956079 
-1.0 0.01977828600663557 0.9802217139933644 
-1.0 0.0282631732179981 0.9717368267820019 
-1.0 5.286175141886943E-7 0.9999994713824858 
-1.0 0.004980730957033338 0.9950192690429667 
-1.0 0.004500990037742634 0.9954990099622574 
-1.0 0.013496219124888747 0.9865037808751113 
-1.0 0.0033941767601432665 0.9966058232398568 
-1.0 0.004436071705624729 0.9955639282943753 
-1.0 2.425758250037033E-10 0.9999999997574243 
-1.0 5.4261670963815676E-8 0.999999945738329 
-1.0 4.736895864616017E-9 0.9999999952631042 
-1.0 1.3239231249757209E-5 0.9999867607687501 
-1.0 2.3084949252003764E-7 0.9999997691505075
```

---

I follow these steps for ranking:

```
d=Math.abs( label(1) - label(-1) )
```

(e.g. 0.96071=0.01964 - 0.98035)

```
rank=d/2
```

(e.g. rank=0.4803)

Comment: What do you mean by "rank" here? What are you trying to do? BTW, you will be lucky to get good results with default values of the  c and g parameters - you need to do a grid search using validation to find good parameters.

Comment: Suppose i want to retrieve positive images, and SVM gives me 10 Images (8 positive and 2 negative). From that 8 positive images, how to rank most relevant images?                                 Just like in any CBIR(Content Based images retrieval) system, it gives most relevant images.

Answer (score 2):

svm_predict() is giving you the probability that each image is positive, (in second column).
Just rank your images in order of that probability.

Your calculation is equivalent to `rank=Math.abs( label(1) - 0.5 )`. It is hard to see how this is useful as probabilities close to zero end up bigger than those that are above 0.5